# How to convert string to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, flot

I had a string as

```
    string flotdata="[[1,2],[3,6],[8,10]]"
```

How to convert this to javascript array so that i can use it in jquery flot pluggin series data.

This string was returned to script there it needs to be converted into javascript array

Comment: Try with: `var arr = JSON.parse(floatdata);`

Answer (score 6):

Use JSON.parse:

```
var a = JSON.parse("[[1,2],[3,6],[8,10]]");
```

**Edit**

[JSON.parse documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in `JSON.parse()` function:

```
flotdata = "[[1,2],[3,6],[8,10]]";
var my_obj = JSON.parse( flotdata );

// [ [Array[2],Array[2],Array[2]] ]
```

---

Reference - [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

> Parse a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing.

Comment: what is my_obj inside JSON.parse(my_obj) , It may be flotdata

Comment: @sonusindhu - yes, you must have seen it before my edit - refresh your page and you'll see it's already fixed :) Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Yeh now looks Great!!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is:

```
flotdata = "[[1,2],[3,6],[8,10]]";
flotdata = eval(flotdata);
```

Comment: noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo!!! :) hehe... but really... don't use `eval` for this... There is already a function that will do the job. One must have a *really* good excuse to use eval...

Comment: @Lix: why not? JSON is designed to be used with eval.

Comment: @thg435 - ah yes, but who knows where the source of `flotdata` is. It might very well be raw user input! DANGER!!! I might be going a little bit over the top with my cautioning, but if there is already a safer function that handles parsing of JSON strings there needs to be a good reason not to use it.